# 'Close as duplicate' shouldn't offer the question itself as a target

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Suggested potential duplicates should not include the question you're trying to close ;)

[image]

(It happened on [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/10985/2101).)

Comment: What happens if you click on that option?

Comment: You can see that in the original image http://i.stack.imgur.com/pyNWG.png

Answer (score 6):

Just to explain where it is coming from: that suggestion is from the fact that 10985 is a frequently linked and highly upvoted question with (strangely enough) the same tags as itself; but you are absolutely right - it should recuse itself from the dialog. This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Questions can recuse themselves? What kind of AI is going on behind the scenes?